# Ubuntu 16.04 changed Display Driver and Blank Screen on LOGIN

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, display, nvidia-graphics-card

I changed my display driver to NVIDIA in the following screen from the Xorg display to NVIDIA and since this doesn't exist my screen is now blank after I enter my encryption password. Can you please let me know how I can fix this? I am on Ubuntu 16.04. Note I cannot reach terminal from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> as people suggest I am not sure why

[image: NVIDIA driver options]

Comment: Try This..
Run *sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
Run *sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa* and then *sudo apt-get update*
Run *sudo apt-get install nvidia-375*
Reboot and your graphics issue should be fixed.

Comment: How do I get to a screen where I can type the above commands? clt + alt + f1 doesn't get me anywhere :(

Comment: Boot from a live USB or CD, mount the partition as R/W...